# Phpstorm File Encoding Issue

Tags: php, encoding, ide, phpstorm, file-encodings

I have a really frustrating issue with PhpStorm where I try to set my all my project files' encoding to ASCII, but the IDE keeps showing me a warning. When I reload with another encoding, it just messes up my whole code with French syntax.

Here are 2 pictures of my file encoding settings and with the warning:

[image: File Encoding Settings]
[image: File Encoding Settings 2]

I've been looking around for an answer and only saw a thread doing exactly what I did, but they didn't have my issue.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Oldskool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the support and apparently it is a issue with one of the plugin installed called Color Ide 2.3